# Updating parent themes vs. updating starter theme

Tags: framework, parent-theme

## Context:

I use framework parent themes (e.g. Thematic) mainly because it ensures that my custom themes inherit cutting-edge and standard compliant code.

## Why I'm not yet using starter themes:

I'm reluctant to use starter themes (e.g. _s, Bones etc.) because, as I understand it, I'll need to screen for code changes with every version update and then manually apply them to my custom theme. I'd rather

## My question:

Is my understanding of the process of updating starter themes correct and if so, is it not less work to simply **reverse engineer a parent theme once and have automated version** updates rather than **repeatedly manually (and perhaps tediously) having to update my custom starter theme**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable child themes for any theme:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

If you want your parent theme based off another parent theme, for example you want a theme based off of *Twitter bootstrap* and apply any changes they make to your framework, without over-riding your changes, use revision control.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/)
[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
etc.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could effectively use a starter theme as a parent theme. Thanks for introducing me to those revision control tools. I guess one _can_ have one's cake and eat it.

Comment: Isn't the whole concept of a "starter theme" to avoid using a child theme? I am having the same confusion myself (starter vs child) BUT i am debating using starter by itself versus starteer with child

Answer (score 0):

What kind of updates are you talking about?

Your understanding is basically correct: if you make a theme from a starter theme, that theme won't be automatically updated.

But depending on what kind of updates you're talking about, your themes shouldn't need to be updated every time a new version of WordPress is released.  New versions of WP don't make old themes instantly obsolete.  I've been using my own fork of HTML5 Starkers for over 3 years now, and sites I wrote 3 years ago are still just fine, even in WP 3.5.  I haven't had to update the theme.  Someday, I'm sure, the themes will start to have some problems, but websites generally have a short shelf-life anyway, and I make sure my clients understand that even if you don't get an entirely new website every few years, most websites will need some maintenance every once in a while.

Comment: To answer your question, the "updates" I'm referring to are the code changes that occur when a new version of a theme is released and thereafter installed. I'm not referring to core WordPress updates. Thanks for sharing your experience with starter themes.